# Using onClick in button to a view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, sdk

Just started learning Android this morning, need help on this. I have few buttons in my App, I want when a user clicks a button a image will be shown and back button to load main.xml .

Code:

**In main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:id="@+id/b1"
           android:text="xyz"
           android:background="#ff3375"
           android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        />

    <Button 
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:id="@+id/b2"
           android:layout_toRightOf="@id/b1"
           android:text="abc"
           android:background="#ff3375"
           android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        /></RelativeLayout>
```

And in Activity.java

```
package com.sam;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class A2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button a,b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        a= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });}}
```

Now, what do I need to add inside the onCLick method to open a image or a XML file and also a back button to return to main.xml

Comment: in your sam.xml file you didn't added any imageview then how the image will be displayed when clicking on the button

Comment: I added that image in background

Answer (score 1):

please explain your question a little further . what do you mean open an image or xml file? do you mean to create a bitmap ? do you mean to show it? if so , where? also , what do you mean that the back button will return to main.xml? main.xml is a layout file , not an activity .

in any case, maybe you meant that you wish to open an image in full screen upon pressing on the button  ,and when clicking on the back button of the device go back to the activity you've created?

if so , you can create a new class that extends Activity , update the manifest so that it would be reachable , and start it (using startActivity) . in the new activity class , set the content view to be of an ImageView that shows an image , or of a layout file that has an imageView that shows an image .

---

for starting a new activity , you need to call :

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
```

where "CurrentActivity" is the current activity that you are at (called "A2Activity" in your sample) and "NewActivity" is the one that shows the image.

as written before , do not forget to update the manifest.

Comment: Ya you got me right, I created a new class and did all and now in onClick method I am trying this ~ Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setClass(view.getContext(), im1.class);
       startActivity(intent);~  , but it is showing Intent can't be resolved to a type

Comment: Now I am geting only this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContext() from the type View

Comment: updated my answer . btw , you don't have to declare the buttons variables , not as buttons (since views are also clickable) and not at all (since you don't use them later) . also , classes in java (and android) should start with an uppercase letter . that's the standard .

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Can you please tell where I am doing wrong. I created a class called im1.java and inside it I did  setContentView(R.layout.sam); and created a xml layout called sam.xml and changed background to     android:background="@drawable/samm" . Don't understand it doesn't shows any error but emulator crashes. And how to implement a button in that view to call main.xml

Comment: I have uploaded the project, please help me to sort out the errors: http://smrtm.in/G7u

Comment: yes, i can help , but please update your question since i can't read your code without seeing it :) . about crashes , try to read the logs (especially the red lines) and double click them so that will (usually) get you directly to the cause of the crash . about the button , why would you like to add a button while all android devices have it as a hardware button ? that's not like on iphone which doesn't have any button ...

Comment: I wish to open an image in full screen upon pressing a the button, I have done the way you have said and even uploaded the project in the above. But for some reason the App crashes

Comment: i can't see your updated answer with the code you've written about. you also haven't checked the logs or debug in order to see what's wrong .

Comment: I have only added this to Mainfest: <activity android:name=".im1" ></activity>. Do I need to add anything more. THis is what I have created the workflow: A2Activity->main.xml->onCLick->startActivity->im1.java->sam.xml .But it says it can't find the explicit  activity class, but I have already added it to mainfest

Comment: again , please add your most updated code (of both the manifest and the java files) so that i can see what's wrong.

Comment: you didn't change even one character in your question for at least an hour . please add the manifest file and the code of the new activity class. also, why can't you debug on your own ? you simply click on the "bug" button .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12521/discussion-between-samrat-mazumdar-and-android-developer)